# Javascript: onclick window.open happens more than once

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am trying to make it when a user clicks anywhere on the page, a new tab opens. I only want this to happen once, as it would other-wise make it hard for them to navigate around my site. Here is my code:

```
document.onclick = function() {
    window.open('http://example.com');
};
```

My problem is like I said, it happens every time a user clicks. How can I make it so it only happens once?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a flag! change to false when the clicks execute for first time

Comment: What if the user accidentally closed the popup and wants to re-open it?

Comment: try this window.open('http://example.com','_test');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply keep the count !

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var count=0;
document.onclick=function()
{
  if(count==0){
   window.open('http://example.com');
   }
 ++count;
}
</script>
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just remove that `onclick` should be enough:

```
document.onclick = function() {
    window.open('http://example.com');
    document.onclick = null;
};
```

Demo:

```js
document.onclick=function() {
  alert('only show once!');
  // Unset the onclick function.
  document.onclick = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a name for the window

```
window.open('http://example.com','_test');
```

Comment: I think that this is the proper answer, because the other answers take not into account that the user could have closed the popup (by accident) and wants to open it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jquery:

```
$(document).one('click', function() {
   window.open('your-url')
});
```